# Add 1 to vector<unsigned char> value - Histogram in C++

Tags: c++, vector, histogram, vision

I guess it's such an easy question (I'm coming from Java), but I can't figure out how it works.

I simply want to increment an vector element by one. The reason for this is, that I want to compute a histogram out of image values. But whatever I try I just can accomplish to assign a value to the vector. But not to increment it by one!

This is my histogram function:

```
void histogram(unsigned char** image, int height,
        int width, vector<unsigned char>& histogramArray) {

    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {


//          histogramArray[1] = (int)histogramArray[1] + (int)1;
// add histogram position by one if greylevel occured
            histogramArray[(int)image[i][j]]++;
        }
    }
// display output
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        cout << "Position: " << i << endl;
        cout << "Histogram Value: " << (int)histogramArray[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

But whatever I try to add one to the histogramArray position, it leads to just 0 in the output. I'm only allowed to assign concrete values like:

```
histogramArray[1] = 2;
```

Is there any simple and easy way? I though iterators are hopefully not necesarry at this point, because I know the exakt index position where I want to increment something.

EDIT:
I'm so sorry, I should have been more precise with my question, thank you for your help so far! The code above is working, but it shows a different mean value out of the histogram (difference of around 90) than it should. Also the histogram values are way different than in a graphic program - even though the image values are exactly the same! Thats why I investigated the function and found out if I set the histogram to zeros and then just try to increase one element, nothing happens! This is the commented code above:

```
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                histogramArray[1]++;
    // add histogram position by one if greylevel occured
                // histogramArray[(int)image[i][j]]++;
            }
        }
```

So the position 1 remains 0, instead of having the value height*width. Because of this, I think the correct calculation histogramArray[image[i][j]]++; is also not working properly.

Do you have any explanation for this? This was my main question, I'm sorry.

Just for completeness, this is my mean function for the histogram:

```
unsigned char meanHistogram(vector<unsigned char>& histogram) {
    int allOccurences = 0;
    int allValues = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        allOccurences += histogram[i] * i;
        allValues += histogram[i];
    }
    return (allOccurences / (float) allValues) + 0.5f;
}
```

And I initialize the image like this:

```
unsigned char** image= new unsigned char*[width];
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
image[i] = new unsigned char[height];
}
```

But there shouldn't be any problem with the initialization code, since all other computations work perfectly and I am able to manipulate and safe the original image. But it's true, that I should change width and height - since I had only square images it didn't matter so far.
The Histogram is created like this and then the function is called like that:

```
vector<unsigned char> histogramArray(256);
histogram(array, adaptedHeight, adaptedWidth, histogramArray);
```

So do you have any clue why this part histogramArray[1]++; don't increases my histogram?  histogramArray[1] remains 0 all the time! histogramArray[1] = 2; is working perfectly. Also histogramArray[(int)image[i][j]]++; seems to calculate something, but as I said, I think it's wrongly calculating.
I appreciate any help very much! The reason why I used a 2D Array is simply because it is asked for. I like the 1D version also much more, because it's way simpler!

Comment: The problem is with your array indexing... `image[i][j]` doesn't work as you need given a pointer-to-pointer-to-char... how is it supposed to know the array dimensions when they're not in the type?  You probably want to pass an `unsigned char*` then index (once) to `image[i * width + j]`, but it depends which of `i` and `j` vary fastest in your data layout.  In C++, it's common to write a multi-dimension-array class that allows e.g. `image(i,j)` notation to access the element you think of as `[i][j]`.

Comment: I would add a line `std::cout << image[i][j] << std::endl;` to make sure that you are accessing the right element of `histogramArray`. Also, have you made sure that `histogramArray` has the required elements? How many items do you expect to see in `histogramArray`? A `map` might be appropriate if you don't know the size of `histogramArray` ahead of time.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you've posted (You have superfluous casts but they wouldn't cause a problem).  I suspect a problem in the code that calls the `histogram()` function, can you show that (including the entirety of the setup of the arguments you are passing in).

Comment: As @TonyD writes, the problem is in your `image`. You need to post the code where you allocate your image. Where does it come from? Do you indeed do `height+1` memory allocations for each image? (That's probably the only way that this code would make sense.) The rest of your code is fine; the only problem point is the way you allocate and index your image.

Comment: As Matt says, there shouldn't be anything wrong. I can use my image for other calculations and modify it correctly and print images correctly. I'm sorry being so unprecise with my question. The part histogramArray[(int)image[i][j]]++; is counting something. But I'm pretty sure that it's wrong. Because my image values are correct, but my output histogram differs from graphic program histograms. I figured out if I try histogramArray[1]++; the position [1] remains 0! It is not increasing.

Comment: If I try histogramArray[1] = 2; the position [1] is set to 2?! Why? Maybe this is the same cause of problems for the correct histogram as with histogramArray[(int)image[i][j]]++;. Do you have any idea why this is not incrementing?
Thank you very much for your help so far! And yes I like 1D arrays much more, but I had to use 2D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see, the current problem in your code is **not** incrementing a value versus assigning to it; *it's the way you index your image*. The way you've written your `histogram` function and the image access part puts very fine restrictions on how you need to allocate your images for this code to work.

For example, assuming your histogram function is as you've written it above, none of these image allocation strategies will work: (I've used `char` instead of `unsigned char` for brevity.)

```
char image [width * height]; // Obvious; "char[]" != "char **"
char * image = new char [width * height]; // "char*" != "char **"
char image [height][width]; // Most surprisingly, this won't work either.
```

The reason why the third case won't work is tough to explain simply. Suffice it to say that a 2D array like this will not implicitly decay into a pointer to pointer, and if it did, it would be meaningless. Contrary to what you might read in some books or hear from some people, in C/C++, arrays and pointers are *not* the same thing!

Anyway, for your histogram function to work correctly, you have to allocate your image like this:

```
char** image = new char* [height];
for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i)
    image[i] = new char [width];
```

Now you can fill the image, for example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j)
        image[i][j] = rand() % 256; // Or whatever...
```

On an image allocated like this, you can call your histogram function and it will work. After you're done with this image, you have to free it like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i)
    delete[] image[i];
delete[] image;
```

For now, that's enough about allocation. I'll come back to it later.

In addition to the above, it is **vital** to note the order of iteration over your image. The way you've written it, you iterate over your columns on the outside, and your inner loop walks over the rows. Most (all?) image file formats and many (most?) image processing applications I've seen do it *the other way around*. The memory allocations I've shown above also assume that the first index is for the row, and the second is for the column. I suggest you do this too, unless you've very good reasons not to.

No matter which layout you choose for your images (the recommended row-major, or your current column-major,) it is in issue that you should always keep in your mind and take notice of.

Now, on to my recommended way of allocating and accessing images and calculating histograms.

I suggest that you allocate and free images like this:

```
// Allocate:
char * image = new char [height * width];

// Free:
delete[] image;
```

That's it; no nasty (de)allocation loops, and every image is one contiguous block of memory. When you want to access row `i` and column `j` (note which is which) you do it like this:

```
image[i * width + j] = 42;
char x = image[i * width + j];
```

And you'd calculate the histogram like this:

```
void histogram (
    unsigned char * image, int height, int width,
     // Note that the elements here are pixel-counts, not colors!
    vector<unsigned> & histogram
) {
    // Make sure histogram has enough room; you can do this outside as well.
    if (histogram.size() < 256)
        histogram.resize (256, 0);

    int pixels = height * width;
    for (int i = 0; i < pixels; ++i)
        histogram[image[i]]++;
}
```

I've eliminated the printing code, which should not be there anyway. Note that I've used a single loop to go through the whole image; this is another advantage of allocating a 1D array. Also, for this particular function, it doesn't matter whether your images are row-major or column major, since it doesn't matter in what order we go through the pixels; it only matters that we go through all the pixels and nothing more.

**UPDATE**: After the question update, I think all of the above discussion is moot and notwithstanding! I believe the problem could be in the declaration of the histogram vector. It should be a vector of `unsigned int`s, not single bytes. Your problem seems to be that the value of the vector elements seem to stay at zero when your simplify the code and increment just one element, and are off from the values they need to be when you run the actual code. Well, this could be a symptom of numeric wrap-around. If the number of pixels in your image are a a multiple of 256 (e.g. 32x32 or 1024x1024 image) then it is natural that the sum of their number would be 0 mod 256.

I've already alluded to this point in my original answer. If you read my implementation of the `histogram` function, you see in the signature that I've declared my vector as `vector<unsigned>` and have put a comment above it that says this victor counts pixels, so its data type should be suitable.

I guess I should have made it bolder and clearer! I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: This is such a great post. You really wrapped everything very fine. But unfortunately I have to say, that I did everything like you suggested. I initialized the image exactly this way. I just messed up with the width and height initialization because I have only square images and didn't spent any attention to this (thank you for the hint!). Also I have to use 2D Arrays-unfortunately .. I edited my Question above. Maybe you can have a look at? My histogramArray[(int)image[i][j]]++; is working, but if I just try histogramArray[1]++; this position is not changing. It stays 0.

Comment: This is important because I investigated my histogram mean function and found out that it differs from a normal mean function of the image. But my image values are correct, so I found out that my histogram is very different from an graphic program. I started investigating the incrementing part and found out, that it is not working in the simple example. Thats why belief now, that also the histogramArray[(int)image[i][j]]++; is not increasing properly. Maybe you can have a look at my code above. But thank you very much for your post, it's awesome. Maybe it helps other googlers!

Comment: @ManWithConcern: I've added an "update" section to my answer. Tell me, is the dimensions of your images a multiple of 256, by any chance?!

Comment: Believe it or not, I came accross this error 1 minute ago and wanted to report my sillyness here. But you were one hour faster :D! That was the issue!!!

Comment: I don't know why I was so stupid also initializing the histogram with unsigned char. Of course I need more space. My Image is 512x512. It was just so confusing and distracting from this problem, because I got always 0 for incrementing. But your answer makes totally sense. 512*512 mod 256 is exactly 0 xD. Thank you very much for your fantastic help! answer accepted ;D.